# Swift get content text response after send request to web service

Tags: swift

I know how to get data response from url. But the data response contains html source[image]. Although I can handle it to get what I need but will be better if I know how to get only text. I use:

```
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)
    {
        data, response, error in guard
            let data = data, error == nil else
        {
            // check for fundamental networking error
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        result = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
    }
    task.resume()
```

Comment: Can you describe the kind of answer you're expecting here? If the server sends you information, what mechanism are you envisioning to not receive it? When you say "only text", all the data you've shown here is "text." What kind of algorithm do you have in mind? By "only text" do you mean "all the text up to the first newline?" Or "all the text up to the first `<`?" Or something else? If the server has a way to request a different format (one without HTML), we would need to know what this service is in order to help you. It's strange to return a line of non-HTML followed by HTML like this.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this.

```swift
let text = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self) // Convert data to string
    .components(separatedBy: "\n")               // Split string into multiple line 
    .first                                       // Get the first line
```

Comment: Hi, as said: Although I can handle it to get what I need but will be better if I know how to get only text

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. This will return just the text you have circled in your image. If you need something different, maybe update your question with more details.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the endpoint has an option (like a query parameter) to return only the text, then you will get whatever the server wants to send and you will need to sort it out client side.